# Add Payment Method to an existing customer

Tags: stripe-payments, rest, angular10

In my angular app I want to use the stripe-API. I want to add a payment method to the customer. e.g. SEPA
My first Problem is to choose the right endpoint. I think it is the "create source"-endpoint.
My second problem is to pass the correct params. My postman body looks like

```
{
  type: 'sepa_debit',
  sepa_debit: {iban: 'DE12345678901234567890'},
  currency: 'eur',
  customer: 'cus_Jjg6mhSRHZuXYZ'
  owner: {
    name: 'Max Mustermann',
}
```

Response:

```
"error": {
    "code": "parameter_unknown",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
    "message": "Received unknown parameters: type, sepa_debit",
    "param": "type",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
}
```

the docs says that type can be 'sepa_debit'...?
Can someone pls hepl me?

Comment: "the docs says that type can be 'sepa_debit'" - hard to say what's going on here. Post a full curl snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Payment Methods API instead of Sources API. If you have an existing Payment Method, you can [attach](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach) it to a Customer.

You can also create a Payment Method, attach it *and* start a new payment flow at the same time when [creating a Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method_data).

Comment: Hi Sergio,
thank you. This works fine.
But I am a little confused because I have an stripe-connected WooCommerce  too. When I add a new payment method there it will be added also as source.
The added method from the Payment Method API does not display in WooCommerce.

Comment: @KingGilbert: ah yes, that may be a problem. Check if there's a new release of WooCommerce that works with PaymentMethods/PaymentIntents instead of Sources. PM/PI is the preferred/recommended API. That said, Sources should still work too, for the time being. Unfortunately, you didn't post enough info to troubleshoot your original attempt.

Comment: Your Explanation was perfect. Thank you